# linq select m:n user:groups

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I've got three tables:

```
cp_user (id, name)
cp_group (id, name)
cp_usergroup (user_id, group_id)
```

- the classical m:n stuff.

Assume the following Data:

```
cp_user
1, Paul
2, Steven

cp_group
1, Admin
2, Editor

cp_usergroup
1, 1
1, 2
2, 2
```

So Paul is in the Admin AND Editor group, while Steven is just in the Editor group. I want to generate a list like that from the database:

```
Paul Admin
Paul Editor
Steven Editor
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!
Clemens

Answer (score 2):

A friend of mine just helped me out on this:

```
var q = db2.cp_users.SelectMany(
          u => u.cp_groups.Select(
              g => new { Username = u.name, Groupname = g.name }));
```

Works fine for me. Is there any way to do this in query syntax?

Answer (score 1):

In query syntax:

```
from u in db2.cp_users
from g in u.cp_groups
select new { Username = u.name, GroupName = g.name }
```

Comment: Hmmm, sorry to say, but this returns

    Paul Admin
    Steven Admin
    Paul Editor
    Steven Editor

It seems the tables are just cross-joined.

Comment: Are you saying the first solution (in fluent syntax) returns the results you want, but the query expression doesn't?